# RenderSection set as required:false, but still throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This code supposed to mark my Section as optional.

```
_layout.cshtml 
@RenderSection("ViewStyles",false)
```

or

```
@RenderSection("ViewStyles",required:false)
```

I tried both.

Yet, it throws an exception

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I tried adding an empty section to my views that don't need to use the ViewStyles section

```
@section ViewStyles {  }
```

but I still get the same exception.

Is there another workaround?

Comment: every time I have seen that error it is because of using a list that wasn't initialized.  Make sure you have list = new list on all of your lists before you populate them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***This has nothing to do with your section.*** I'm not sure where you got the idea that the section being empty is generating this error, but that is categorically *not* what's happening. `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` is a runtime error generated when you attempt to reference a property off of a variable that evaluates to null. There's some piece of code somewhere that is referencing a property off a *variable* (again, not talking about sections here) when that variable itself resolves to `null` at runtime.

For example, lets say you do something like:

```
Foo foo = db.Foos.Find(id);
```

The `variable` foo is defined as a `Foo`, so you can reference any property off of it that `Foo` has. If your `Foo` class had a property named `Bar`. Then you might then try to get the value of this property somewhere in your code via:

```
foo.Bar
```

That will compile just fine. However, if no `Foo` with the id is found, then the actual value of `foo` is `null`, and `null` does *not* have a property named `Bar`, which can only be determined at runtime. That is what the error is telling you is happening: ***somewhere in your code, you're calling a property of some variable without checking for a null value of the variable first***. In the example above, you would typically do something like:

```
Foo foo = db.Foos.Find(id);
if (foo != null)
{
    bar = foo.Bar;
}
```

You can also employ a ternary to provide some sort of fallback:

```
bar = foo != null ? foo.Bar : "Baz";
```

That way, `bar` will either hold the value of `foo.Bar` or if `foo` is null, the string `"Baz"`.

Comment: OMG... No, I'm not saying the section resolves to null; I'm saying you're not doing proper null checking in some other area of your application. The error has absolutely nothing whatsoever at all to do with the section.

Comment: you're absolutely correct about "some code returning" null and its properties are being used without proper checks. At the end, the problem was in the _contentLayout. It expected a specific model to be passed to it from the controller. I am not sure why the debugger chose to highlight the RenderSection() among all other helper methods. I apologize for my negative comment! Your answer did send me on the right path to find the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

@Chris-Pratt led me in the right direction with his detailed answer.  I wanted to share my code to help out:

My issue was **@RenderSection("Header", false)** coming back “Object reference not set to an instance of an object”.  Stepping throw the code, it would not step pass and break:

[image: header section]

Finally, I realized it was the next line of code that breaking:

```
<body class="@TempData[AppConstants.GlobalClass].ToString() 
         loggedin-@(User.Identity.Name.ToString().ToLower())">
```

**@TempData** was null

Answer (score 1):

I had the @RenderSection("ViewStyles",required:false) but was still getting error due to a missing app setting which is being used in my layout page.